# wp_insert_post() White Screen / Blank Page

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a custom post from a front end form.
The post is successfully created but leading to white screen where the form is implemented.

Here is my code:-

```
$new_post_args = array(
                                'post_title'    => 'Lead is being updated',
                                'post_status'   => 'publish', 
                                'post_type'     => 'hg-rma',
                                'post_author'   => 4470,
                            );  

            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post_args);
            if($post_id)
            {
                $update_post_args = array(
                                            'ID'            =>  $post_id,
                                            'post_title'    =>  $post_id,
                                        );
                wp_update_post( $update_post_args );
```

The above code leads to whitescreen / blank page, however the post is created in back end. But not updated as in above code.

When i change the 'post_status' to draft, It works. I think it may be a capability issue.

Below is code that is registering my post type:-

```
add_action('init', 'hg_rma_post_type');
function hg_rma_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'HG RMA',
        'singular_name' => 'HG RMA',
        'menu_name' => 'HG RMA',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'HG RMA',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New RMA',
        'new_item' => 'New RMA',
        'edit_item' => __('Edit RMA'),
        'view_item' => __('View RMA'),
        'all_items' => __('All RMA'),
        'search_items' => __('Search RMA'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent RMA:'),
        'not_found' => __('No RMA found.'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No RMA found in Trash.')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __('Description.'),
        'public' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'hg-rma-panel'
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 51,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'author'
        ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true
    );

    register_post_type('hg-rma', $args);
}
```

I have other similar form exists on my website that interacts with other custom post types, but they are not creating such problems.

I will be really thankful, if anyone can help me out regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround while R&D

Set post_status to 'future' and set post_date to '1 minute later'.

```
$current_date               = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$post_date                  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minute',strtotime($current_date)));
$new_post_args = array(
                                'post_title'    => 'Lead is being updated',
                                'post_status'   => 'future', 
                                'post_type'     => $post_type,
                                'post_author'   => 4470,
                                'post_date'     =>  $post_date,
                            );  

            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post_args);
```